# Searching through a Hashmap for a value, adding that value + key to set and returning the completed set

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

So i have a class called Garage and a second class called customer, so far the class Garage constructs as follows:

```
public class Garage

private Map <String, Customer> customers;

/**
* Constructor for objects of class Garage, implements the customers instance 
variable and assigns it a HashMap
*/
public Garage()
{
  customers = new HashMap<String, Customer>(); 
}

/**
* Adds a Customer to the Garage Hashmap customers. 
*/
public void addCustomer (String regNo, String name, String address, int area)
{
  Customer aCustomer = new Customer (name,address, area);
  this.customers.put(regNo,aCustomer) ;

}

/**
* Prints out a list of customers from the HashMap customers. 
*/
public void printCustomers()
{
 Set set = customers.entrySet();
  Iterator cusIterator = set.iterator();

 while (cusIterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)cusIterator.next();
    System.out.println(mentry.getValue());}
  }

  /**
   * Finds Customer information from customers Hashmap based on registration 
 key. 
   */
  public void findCustomerWithReg(String aReg)
  {
     if (customers.containsKey(aReg)){
        System.out.println (aReg +" "+ customers.get(aReg));
  }
     else {
        System.out.println (aReg + " is not found in the database");}
```

}

Then Customer looks like:

```
public class Customer
{

private String fullName;
private String address;
private int area;

/**
* Constructor for objects of class Customer
*/
public Customer(String aName, String anAddress, int anArea)
{
  // initialise instance variables
  this.fullName = aName;
  this.address = anAddress;
  this.area = anArea;
}

public String getName()
{
  return this.fullName;
}

public String getAddress()
{
  return this.address;
}

public int getArea()
{
  return this.area;
}

public String toString()
{
  return (this.getName() + " " + this.getAddress() + " area: " + 
 this.getArea());
 }
 }
```

My issue is with the Garage Class in particular this method:

```
public void findCustomerWithReg(String aReg)
  {
     if (customers.containsKey(aReg)){
        System.out.println (aReg +" "+ customers.get(aReg));
  }
     else {
        System.out.println (aReg + " is not found in the database");}
```

i'd now like to be able to search through the customer details held as a value such as:

String, String, int

add them to a new set and return them. in essence searching through the original Hashmap to find a unique value, adding the key +value to a set and returning the completed set once the full Hashmap has been searched and all values are added.

Hope that hasn't overly confused it! New to java and very much learning so i'd appreciated any help i can get :)

Comment: Can you try explaining a little bit better with some examples?

Comment: Sure Jacob,

So i have one HashMap that contains say:

<String, Obj>

Which reads as

123ABC, name, Address, Area

What i'd like to do is search that obj within that HashMap and return all baskets / lines that have say Area 3 or Area 2?

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't make sense.  I understand that you currently have a `Map<String, Customer>`.  Are you saying that you want to retain every `Customer` within that map that has an 'Area' of 2 or 3?  It would help if you could edit your post and add the code for `Customer.java`.

Comment: Edited & Updated :)

Comment: *once the full Hashmap has been searched and all values are added*. There can only ever be one value for a given key. And it's not clear what you want to do with it.

Comment: Oh, you want to search using a property of the value instead of the key, is that right?

Comment: Just iterate over the entry set and check each one, kind of like you're doing in `printCustomers()`.

Comment: Can you show me roughly?